# How to concatenat or bind any hard code value with database returned value?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am writing a select query like that "`select Data from table1 where 1d=1`" that will return me output like that

```
id   Data
1     10
```

now i want output like that

```
id  Temp  Data
1    2     10
```

the query "select '2',Data from table1 where 1d=1" give me the required output.But when database return null It should be like that

```
id  Temp  Data
1    2    null
```

But it will return 0 row.Kindly tell me the query to get the required output . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a *dummy* record when no data found on a condition, then you can try the following:

```
select id, '2' as Temp, Data from table1 where id=1
union all
select 1, '2', null
limit 1
```

Use of `limit` here will restrict results to `1 row`, when first `select` fetches a row and when it fetches none, then uses the last `null` entry dummy row.

If the first query results more than one row, you should depend on the size of the result set to decide whether to read or stop reading the last record. For this you have to remove `limit` clause.